# g++ header files in include subdirectory

Tags: c++, include

I'm including the freetype2 library by calling the freetype2/ft2build.h header file.

```
#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
```

The header file itself calls another header file in a subdirectory.

```
#include <config/ftheader.h>
```

Which causes the 'make' to fail.

```
/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h:37:29: fatal error: config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory
#include <config/ftheader.h>
```

The '**config**' subdirectory is within the '**freetype2**', but the compiler is clearly looking for it in the **/usr/include** directory.

I cannot find a solution to this, but I can't possibly be the only one it affects. What am I missing?

I've tried adding `INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/freetype2/config` to the makefile but this doesn't work.

Makefile is as follows

```
INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/freetype2
CC=g++
LDLIBS=-lglut -lGLEW -lGL
all: main
clean:
    rm -f *.o main
.PHONY: all clean
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to replace

```
#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
```

with

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

and use

```
INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/freetype2
```

in makefile

Comment: Thanks, but now it can't find `ft2build.h`. :(

Comment: Pls. edit your post to include full makefile or command you use to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my Mkefile.

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/freetype2  -I/usr/include/freetype2/config
CC=g++
LDLIBS=-lglut -lGLEW -lGL
all: main
clean:
    rm -f *.o main
.PHONY: all clean
```

from INCLUDE to CPPFLAGS.